# Cakephp 2.0: How to provide ORDER BY instructions for data retrieved recursively through find()?

Tags: model-view-controller, sql-order-by, cakephp-2.0, recursive-query

I am trying to set up a model with a lot of hasMany/hasOne relationships, and I'd like for the owned models to be presented, *alphabetically*, in a drop-down menu within the "Add" view. I am not sure how to provide ORER BY instructions to models that are retrieved recursively. This is what I've tried:

```
$services =  $this->service->find('all', array(
                                       'order'=>array(
                                               'Service.start_year DESC',
                                               'Servicecat.title DESC'
                                               ), 
                                        'recursive'=>0
                                          ) );
```

But of course this yields no change. I have a suspicion it's not very complicated, I just can't find a solution in the cookbook/api. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this a few ways. I prefer to use the containable behavior for models and then it allows you to finely control how the models are retrieved. You could also setup order in your model's relationship definition.

**Model Way**

```
$hasMany = array(
    'Servicecat' => array(
        'order' => array(
            'Servicecat.title DESC'
        )
    )
);
```

**Containable Way**

In your models, set them to use the containable behavior:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then, when you find from your controller, you can explicitly state which models are linked. You can use multidimensional arrays to determine the depth of recursion.

```
$services = $this->Service->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'contains' => array(
             'Servicecat' => array(
                 'order' => array('Servicecat.title' => 'DESC')
             )
         ),
         'order' => array('Services.start_year' => 'DESC')
    )
);
```

Comment: How we can sort in case we want our whole result to be sorted by the inner model. Suppose I have association of User and Events table and also User and UserProfile table. Now in my view I am showing the  events list with the name of the user from User Profile. I want to have sort by functionality with the User Name but the data I am fetching is from the Event table which is associated with the User and User is associated with the UserProfile. I want to sort eventList on the basis of username . Is it possible ?